# Beautiful Soup - Python - crawler stops in the middle of the job - no error shown

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am new to both Python and Webcrawler. This is a task for a Seminar at Uni that I have to finish, but I am having trouble since I have to crawl a huge amount of pages but my crawler keeps stopping halfway. It crawled about half of the pages (reached 1000 pages, but the total is ~2,800) and then it stopped, but did not show any error. I dont know how to fix this. Can you guys please help!

My code is as below:

```
#import the libraries

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib.request
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    import csv
    import re
    import time
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    #create the lists to put information into
    name = []
    txhash = []
    age = []
    fr = []
    to = []
    quantity = []
    transaction_code = []
    token_name = []
    last_page = []
    url = []
    #monitor the time when crawl the pages
    start1 = time.time()

    #crawl the main page to get the contract name and the name of the token
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
    }
    #number of pages in the main page is 18, run the loop through all 18 pages to get a list of token codes
    for i_main in range(1, 2): #19):
        req_main = Request('https://etherscan.io/tokens?p=' + str(i_main), data=None, headers=headers) 
        webpage_main = urlopen(req_main).read()
        urlopen(req_main).close()
        page_soup_main = BeautifulSoup(webpage_main, 'html.parser')
        table_main = page_soup_main.find_all("div", {"class": "table-responsive"})
        table_link_main = table_main[0].find_all("a")

        #create the loop for each token in a page (about 50 tokens/a page, total: 18 pages, last page only has 2 tokens)
        for i in range(5, 9, 3):#len(table_link_main) - 1, 3):
            transaction_code.append(table_link_main[i]['href'][7:])
            token_name.append(table_link_main[i].text)


    print('transaction code:', len(transaction_code)) #852
    print('token_name:', len(token_name)) #852

    for i_url in range(0, len(transaction_code)):

        url.append('https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokentxns2?contractAddress=' + str(transaction_code[i_url]) +'&a=')

    #print(url) 
    print('url:', len(url)) #852
    for i_last_page in range(0, len(url)):
        print(i_last_page)
        req = Request(url[i_last_page], data=None, headers=headers)
        webpage = urlopen(req).read()
        urlopen(req).close()
        page_soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
        #find results within a table
        table = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class": "table-responsive"})
        #token = token_name[i]
        #find number of the pages
        paging_panel= table[0].find_all("b")
        no_page = paging_panel[1].text
        last_page.append(no_page)   
        time.sleep(2) #prevent from getting blocked
    print('last page:', len(last_page)) #852

    end1 = time.time()
    print('time to create all lists (seconds):', end1 - start1)

    #monitor the main crawl
    start2 = time.time()

    for i_url_2 in range(1, len(url)):
        print(i_url_2)
        token = token_name[i_url_2]
        page_no = int(last_page[i_url_2])
        for i_page_no in range(1, page_no + 1):

                #Print number of pages to control which page we are at 
            print(i_page_no)

                #parse each page
            req_loop = Request(url[i_url_2]+'&mode=&p='+ str(i_page_no), data=None, headers=headers)

                #pause the loop
            webpage_loop = urlopen(req_loop).read()
            urlopen(req_loop).close()
            page_soup_loop = BeautifulSoup(webpage_loop, 'html.parser')

                #find results within a table in each page
            table_loop = page_soup_loop.find_all("div", {"class": "table-responsive"})
            table_link_loop = table_loop[0].find_all("td")

                #TxHash
            for i_txhash in range(0, len(table_link_loop), 7):
                txhash.append(table_link_loop[i_txhash].text)

                #Age
            for i_age in range(1, len(table_link_loop), 7):
                age.append(table_link_loop[i_age].span['title'])

                #From
            for i_from in range(2,len(table_link_loop),7):
                fr.append(table_link_loop[i_from].text)

                #To
            for i_to in range(4,len(table_link_loop),7):
                to.append(table_link_loop[i_to].text)

                #Quantity
            for i_quantity in range(5, len(table_link_loop), 7):
                quantity.append(table_link_loop[i_quantity].text)    

                #Name 
            for i_name in range(1, len(table_link_loop), 7):
                name.append(token)

                #Setting this to prevent from getting blocked
            time.sleep(2)    
        time.sleep(10)

    end2 = time.time()
    print('time to run the main crawl (seconds):', end2 - start2)

    #create dataframe to store the information
    transactions = pd.DataFrame({'Name': name,
                                'TxHash': txhash,
                                'Age': age,
                                'From': fr,
                                'To': to,
                                'Quantity': quantity})
    print(transactions.info())

    #turn the dataframe into a csv file
    transactions.to_csv('transactions.csv')`
```

Comment: Their can be numerous reasons to it: Either a token can be used to fetch limited results in one time or it is possible that the website you are scraping detects the scraping before the program finishes (happens in case of facebook). Another possible scenario could be the website limit itself.

Comment: I tried with a shorter version. It crawled 4000 pages perfectly. I advanced the code to loop through 852 tokens and the code I posted above is to test whether the loop works or not.